How to listen to orientation changes on Flutter
On my app I have to implement a logic that when the device is rotated to landscape, from my current screen I have to navigate to an other specific screen.
I already tried to use the didChangeMetrics() method, but it's not really working since the method is called not only one time (so the navigation is called multiple times), and once I pop back to the screen where the method is implemented, it doesn't listen anymore to device orientation changes.
I also tried OrientationBuilder, but also in this case I have the problem that once I am back to this screen, it doesn't listen anymore to device orientation changes. More over, using this builder means that when the orientation is changed, a new build of the screen is executed, which is not really what I need.
There is a way to just listen to orientation changes without having to rebuild the all screen?
I'm kinda happy with didChangeMetrics() despite being called more than once, but I can't fix the problem of why does not work anymore after I navigate back.

I managed to make didChangeMetrics() to work.
The reasons why the method or OrientationBuilder where not working after the first time was because the screen pushed after the rotation was a Camera screen realized with AwesomeCamera. Probably this lib force the activity to portrait only, that's why when I was popping back the orientation changes where not listened anymore. I fixed with
SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
  DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight,
  DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft,
  DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
]);

